# Simulate LEFT JOIN without using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I wanted to know whether it is possible to simulate a `LEFT JOIN` without using `JOINs`.

I use [this database](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left) and try to simulate this `JOIN` with `SELECT`

```
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

I currently am only able to get the `INNER JOIN`. This is my current query:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

Comment: You do realize that your SQL query above is still a JOIN just using the `,` operator?

Comment: @ultrajohn The first query is the join that I want to transform into a query with out a join

Comment: Both queries have joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a left anti-join query, say:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerName

UNION

SELECT Customers.CustomerName, NULL FROM Customers 
    WHERE Customers.CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders);
```

Comment: In SQL, UNION ALL might be a better choice to obtain the exact equivalence. Also, worth mentioning that your solution corresponds exactly to relational algebra's definition of LEFT JOIN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Left_outer_join_.28.E2.9F.95.29

Comment: If you think about it, in this problem, UNION will give the same output as UNION ALL.

Comment: @ultrajohn Thank you alot!

Comment: @ultrajohn: In this particular case, yes because there's a one-to-many relationship between customer and order. But if there were many-to-many relationship, the removal of duplicate rows might be accidental